# Letter followed by some letters or numbers ending with a period

Tags: python, regex

I am looking to create a Python regular expression to match a specific pattern: The pattern always starts with any upper or lowercase letter, may have any number of letters or numbers after it, and always ends in a period (`.`).

For example, the pattern would match the line that has the question label (e.g: `Q42.`) in this HTML code:

```
<p>Q42. Which of the following newspapers, if any, do you read on a regular 
   basis? Please select all that apply:</p>
<p>NY Times</p>
<p>Chicago Tribune</p>
```

EDIT:
I've tried `[a-zA-Z]\W*\.`

 What that says to me is any letter upper or lower followed by any number or letters upper or lower or numbers followed by a period.

EDIT: 
 
I am just trying to test weather the entire line contains these characters or not. Only looking for a `True` or `False`.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? What didn't work? What is the expected output? We'd love to help you fix code you wrote so far but didn't work, for example.

Comment: Using "O" instead of "Q" in your example input is a sure way to go wrong...

Comment: I've tried `[a-zA-Z]\W*\.`

Comment: @user974407: You can [edit] your question to add more information.

Comment: Are you trying to capture the whole line that includes these characters as well?

Comment: @willOEM Can you clarify? I am trying to see if the sentence has this at all. It might not be the first characters.

Comment: I was not 100% sure from your question whether you are just performing a boolean test on lines to see if they contain the desired characters or if you want to match the characters and parse out the lines that contain them.  If the latter is true, please edit your question to make this clear.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]\w*\.
```

should do it.

`\W` means "any character *except* alphanumerics, so you need the opposite, `\w`.

`\b` is a word boundary, ensuring that we start the match at the beginning of a word.

Comment: Am I wrong? I don't think that works:
`>>> print re.search("\b[a-zA-Z]\w*\.",t)`
`None`
`>>> t`
`'<p>Q42. Which of the following newspapers, if any, do you read on a regular \n
 basis? Please select all that apply:</p>'`

Comment: @user974407: You need to use raw strings with regexes: `r"\b[a-zA-Z]\w*\."`, otherwise `\b` will be misinterpreted as a backspace character.

Comment: Thanks. That does work. You are right. While technically WillOEM's answer matches my question better, I'll use your's because my question labels could have underscores in them.  I still don't totally understand the full concept of `\b`. How is that different than WillOEM's?

Comment: @user974407: His solution would match if the starting letter was found in the middle of an alphanumeric word, too. This is probably just a theoretical problem. For example, if there was a sentence: `"Rick Astley was big in the 80s."`, then his regex would match `s.`, mine wouldn't.

Comment: @user974407: Because `\b` only matches at the start or end of words. That's why it's called a "word boundary" anchor. It doesn't match a *character*, it matches a *position*.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

`[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*\.`

It should be noted that `\w` will match alphanumeric characters and underscores.

Comment: I am trying to see if the line contains those characters.

Comment: Ok, gotcha.  I was not sure if you were trying to pull the entire line out and not just bool test it.

Comment: I think your answer is good. But now looking closer I do believe that Tim's matches betters.
[I apologize](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62252/is-it-poor-form-to-switch-accepted-answers)